# Structured Data: Nesting Triangles (using structs and doing some geometric calculations)

Tags: c++, geometry

> **nestedTriangles.cpp (attached) description:**
>
> The program takes as input a pair of triangles, specified be giving
>   the coordinates of each trangle's vertices. It then determines if
>   either triangle is "nested" within the other, meaning that one
>   triangle lies entirely within the interior of the other.
>
> **Pseudocode:**
>
> One triangle lies within another if and only if all three vertices of
>   the first triangle lie within the interior of the second triangle.
>   Suppose that we have a triangle with vertices A, B, and C, described
>   by the coordinates (xA, yA), (xB, yB), and (xC, yC), respectively. The
>   sides of the triangle are the line segments AB, BC, and CA. A line
>   passing through two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) can be considered to
>   be the set of points (x,y) satisfying the equation f(x,y) = 0 where
>   f(x,y) is given as f(x,y) = (x - x1) (y2 - y1) - (y - y1) (x2 - x1)
>   One of the interesting things about that f(x,y) is that we can use it
>   to determine which "side" of the line an abitrary point (x,y) is on:
>
> If f(x,y) = 0, the point is exactly on the line. All points for which
>   f(x,y) > 0 are on one side of the line, and All points for which
>   f(x,y) < 0 are on the other side So the problem of determining whether
>   a point (x,y) is on the inside of a trangle can be checking the sign
>   of f(x,y) for each of the three lines making up the triangle. A
>   complicating factor is that we don't know, for any given triangle,
>   whether those three signs should be all positive, all negative, or
>   some mixture of the two.
>
> The centroid of a triangle can be computed as the "average" of the x
>   and y coordinates of the vertices: xcen = (xA + xB + xC)/3  ycen = (yA
>   + yB + yC)/3  This point (xcen, ycen) is definitely inside the trangle (unless the triangle is "degenerate" and has no interior points). The
>   problem of determining whether (x,y) is on the inside of a triangle
>   can therefore be resolved by checking to see if it is on the same side
>   of each of the trangle's line segments as (xcen, ycen).
>
> **What I need:**
>
> Filling in a missing struct type for LineSegment, I need each line
>   segment to have two fields, called "endPoint1" and "endPoint2", each
>   of type Point. The Point type is already declared. Then I want to fill
>   in the missing bodies for the functions eval and areOnSameSideOf,
>   which manipulate line segments. I think calling eval from within
>   areOnSameSideOf will simplify the implementation of the latter.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

        /**
         * 2D Cartesian coordinates
         */
        struct Point {
          double x;
          double y;
        };

    /**
     * A simple triangle, modeled as a collection of 3 vertices
     */
    struct Triangle {
      Point vertices[3];
    };

    /**
     * A line segment, indicated by its two endpoints
     */
    struct LineSegment
    {
      Point endPoint1;
      Point endPoint2; 
    }; 

    /**
     * Read a trangle from the input stream.
     *
     * A triangle is presented as a sequence of 6 floating point values,
     * each successive pair of numbers being the x,y coordinates of one vertex.
     *
     * @param t  the triangle being read in
     * @param in the input from which it should be read
     */

    void readTriangle (Triangle& t, istream& in)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
          double x, y;
          in >> x >> y;
          Point p = {x, y};
          t.vertices[i] = p;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Evaluate a point with respect to the equation defining the line
     * passing through a line segment.
     *
     *  A line is defined as the set of points satisfying f(x,y) = 0
     *  where f(x,y) is a function of the form ax + by + c. This function
     *  computes that f(x,y) for an arbitrary point, which might not be
     *  on that line.
     *
     * @param line a line segment
     * @param p a point at which we ant the line function evaluated
     * @return A value that is zero for points on the line, positive for all
     *          points on one side of the line, and negative for all points
     *          on the other side of the line.
     */

    double eval (LineSegment line, Point p)
    {
         //*** see "What I need"
 }




    /**
     * Check two points to see if they lie on the same side of a line
     *
     * @param p1 a point
     * @param p2 another point
     * @param line a line segment
     * @return true iff p1 and p2 are on the same side of the line
     *                  passing through the given line segment.
     *                  If either or both points lie exactly on the line,
     *                  return false.
     */

    bool areOnSameSideOf (Point p1, Point p2, LineSegment line)
    {
      //*** see "What I need"
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if a point lies on the interior of a triangle.
     *
     * @param p a point
     * @param t a triangle
     * @return true iff p lies in the interior of the trangle t
     */

    bool isWithin (Point p, Triangle t)
    {
      Point centroid = {0.0, 0.0};
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
          centroid.x += t.vertices[i].x;
          centroid.y += t.vertices[i].y;

        }
      centroid.x /= 3.0;
      centroid.y /= 3.0;

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
          LineSegment side = {t.vertices[i], t.vertices[(i+1)%3]};
          if (!areOnSameSideOf (p, centroid, side))
        return false;
        }
      return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if one triangle lies entirely within the
     * interior of the other.
     *
     * @param outer
     * @param inner
     * @return true iff inner lies entirely within the interior of outer
     */

    bool contains (Triangle outer, Triangle inner)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
          if (!isWithin(inner.vertices[i], outer))
        return false;
        }
      return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if either of two triangles is
     * entirely contained within the other.
     *
     * @param t1
     * @param t2
     */

    void checkForNesting (Triangle t1, Triangle t2)
    {
      if (contains(t1, t2) || contains(t2, t1))
        cout << "These triangles nest." << endl;
      else
        cout << "These triangles do not nest." << endl;
    }

    int main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
      cout << "Enter the x,y coordinates of three vertices of a triangle: " << flush;
      Triangle t1;
      readTriangle (t1, cin);
      cout << "Enter the x,y coordinates of three vertices of another triangle: " << flush;
      Triangle t2;
      readTriangle (t2, cin);
      checkForNesting (t1, t2);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [baricentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) to check if all the three vertices of one triangle are in the other, and viceversa. Its more simple than your approach I think.

Comment: The question is bad all over the place!

Comment: I'll try to do better next time Dieter! Desperation is no excuse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your "eval" function.

```
double eval (LineSegment line, Point p)
{
   Point p_a = p - line.endPoint1;
   Point l_dir = line.EndPoint2 - line.EndPoint1;

   return p_a.x * l_dir.y - p_a.y * l_dir.x;
}
```

Why this works?

1. `p_a` and `l_dir` are basically your points `p` and `line.EndPoint2` in a coordinates set where `line.endPoint1` is the origin.
2. You can check that the expression `l_dir.x * p_a.y - l_dir.y * p_a.x` is basically the cross product between `l_dir` and `p_a`. Hence it will be positive if `p_a` is on "the left" of `l_dir`, that is if `p` is on the left side of `line`.

Now,  `areOnSameSideOf` is trivial, just check if `eval(line,p1)` and `eval(line,p2)` have the same sign.

```
bool areOnSameSideOf (Point p1, Point p2, LineSegment line)
{
    return eval(line,p1) * eval(line,p2) > 0.0; //Use >= if you want to consider "inside" points which are exactly on the segment "line"
}
```

Your approach is not bad, but there is a "standard" way to do things like this, which is way more efficient.

The core idea is to define the order of the vertices of your triangle always counterclockwise (or clockwise, just pick one).

In order to do so, what we need is a `makeTriangleCounterclockwise` function; we can reuse `eval` to do so.

```
void makeTriangleCounterclockwise(Triangle & t)
{
    LineSegment ab = {t.vertices[1], t.vertices[0]};
    if ( eval(ab,t.vertices[2]) < 0.0) {
            /** vertices[2] is on the "right" of ab. Notice that if this eval returns
exactly zero that means that your triangle is singular**/
        swap(t.vertices[0],t.vertices[1]);
    }
}
```

Now you don't need the centroid of the triangle anymore, since `eval` will always return
positive values for on "the left" and negatives for "on the right", and *you know that the triangle is defined in a counterclockwise order*

```
bool isWithin (Point p, Triangle t)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
   {
      LineSegment side = {t.vertices[i], t.vertices[(i+1)%3]};
      if (eval(side, p) < 0.0)
            return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Side note: better define `LineSegment` as:

```
struct LineSegment {
    Point startPoint,endPoint;
};
```

So people who read your code will actually understand that your segment has a *direction*.

Comment: Thanks for showing mercy and helping me out, sbabbi! I know it was a bad question, I'll probably ask about some further elaborations in the morning.

Comment: @aharper The question itself is fine. Maybe too long, no need for all those lines to explain the problem (no need for geometric definitions, or class definitions when their usage is self-explanatory, the code you post should be contained, etc.). No big deal tho, welcome to SO.

Comment: I keep getting a 'no match for operator- ' error in the eval function when I try to run this code. Happens twice, once for p_a and once for l_dir. But there are no other errors, at least. Any suggestions? Any way that I could make use of the standard library pages (suggestions) that I get shown with these errors? The only 'sugggestions' I could find from that would be syntactical....

Comment: You need to implement an operator- for your `Point` class (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). Or just do it component by component.